# Loading a classpath jar, and still being able to load files from filestream

Tags: java, mysql, classpath

I am trying to load a .properties file, while launching a file with `getResourceAsStream("config.properties")`, which works as long as I run java with no command line options. However, when I try to load mysql, `java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar`, it no longer works. I assume this is because whatever a classpath is, which I will not claim to understand, it is setting the root directory of the project so it results in a file not found exception when looking for the file.

How can I both use mysql connector, while still use file operations, in very simple terms?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding how classpaths work, whenever you specify a package name, you specify the whole package name. For example, suppose you want the Java runtime to find a class named `Cool.class` in the package `utility.myapp`. If the path to that directory is `C:\java\MyClasses\utility\myapp`, you would set the class path so that it contains `C:\java\MyClasses` then to run that app, you could use the following JVM command `java -cp C:\java\MyClasses utility.myapp.Cool`, Source and more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: Using the above method you can specify multiple paths separated by a semicolon ";":  `java -cp C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses ...`

Comment: So, trying to understand, I tried to run ``java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar JobSkills.java``. It gave an error that it has to be ./mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar, so I tried, ``java -cp .;./mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar JobSkills.java``, but then it gives Error: ``Could not find or load main class ?cp```

Comment: my goal is only to be able to load the SQL connector, and still use file operations

Comment: Is your application jar file in the same folder as the SQL library jar file? Note that using `java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar` will only try to run the SQL jar file, not your application.

Comment: Yes, the two are in the same folder, right next to eachother

Comment: In that case lets say the folder is located at `c:\yourApplication\ ` and your jar project was titled `exampleApplication` then you could run the application and load the SQL connector using `java -cp "c:\yourApplication\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar;c:\yourApplication" exampleApplication` (fixed to have the correct SQL version number in the path)

Comment: Thank you, that worked!